# Perform an operation on a subset of columns where column name contains string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have df1 and df2. I want to difference them, `df_new = df1 - df2`. However a few of the columns of df1 and df2 (they have the same columns), I want to do extra operations.

Something like:

```
df_new = df1 - df2 # element-wise on all rows and cols
df_new[df_new[columns where column.name.contains("price_")] *= 100 # mult every row for these cols by 100
df_new[df_new[columns where column.name.contains("spread_")] /= df1 # element-wise for those cols
```

I'm not sure if something like is possible or what the proper functions/syntax would be. Basically after forming `df_new` I just want to go in and conveniently edit some columns, which I identify by a string phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `str.contains` with `loc` to reach those columns:

```
df_new.loc[:, df_new.columns.str.contains("price_")] *= 100 # mult every 
row for these cols by 100
df_new.loc[:, df_new.columns.str.contains("spread_")] /= df1
```

Comment: Thanks! And just to quickly confirm, for the second line `/= df1` will pandas automatically seek out the same column subsets for df1 ? Or I should do the same `[: ,df_new...]` syntax on the right hand side of the assignment too?

Comment: No, it will fill `NaN` the columns that aren't in columns on the left hand side

Comment: OK so I should do it on both sides, got it

Comment: Yes, just to make things clear, when you divide two dataframes with another the result dataframe will contain all columns from both sides. Whether a column will be filled with `NaN` will depend if both dataframes have that particular column

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df_new.loc[:, df_new.columns.str.contains('price_')] *= 100
df_new.loc[:, df_new.columns.str.contains('spread_')] /= df1
```

**Note** you may find `.str.startswith` and `.str.endswith` helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html).

```py
df.filter(like="price_")
```

With `like` it returns all columns that have `price_` in their name (substring). For more complex patterns, use `regex` instead.